# Laravel 8: Make CSS load on both https and http ? (Using AWS right now)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-8

My laravel 8 app would not load on https when I forced AWS to render everything https so I added this line in AppServiceProvider and it worked:

```
   public function boot()
    {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

The question is I'd like the site to work whether it's http or https. What's the equivalent of setting something like this up on laravel 8? Below is a code snippet I found on this site but it does not seem to work for laravel 8, or maybe I'm doing something incorrectly

```
   public function boot()
    {
        if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how you'd solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the protocol when loading the css then the file will be loaded with the same protocol as the request.

If you are behind a proxy that itself terminates the SSL connection then your application will receive only http requests and be confused about what protocol to use on the reply.

How do you specify the link for the css in your view?

If you use the asset() helper then it will add http://

Instead, try just specifying the bare path = `"/assets/css/app.css"`

Comment: Snapey, I follow you on laracasts and thank you for helping students like me. The code above, public function boot() {  URL::forceScheme('https'); } works on my server. Nonetheless, I have too many packages installed (jetstream, ticketit, etc) to identify where all my CSS files are n edit. I clarify my question by asking if there's a catchall method so that the laravel code works whether https is enabled or not? The second block of code I submitted in the question does not seem to work in laravel 8. So I have to add first block of code before I update site each time. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I specify css using  href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}    but that does not seem to load with https enabled. Also, this jetstream installation I don't even know how it's linking css. :D

Comment: If you are working behind a proxy then you should configure Trusted Proxies. see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solve it by editing app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php file

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function register(){}

public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
{
      if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS'))
      {
        $url->forceScheme('https');
      }
}
```

and adding this line on my config/.env

```
REDIRECT_HTTPS=false
```